# XSRF-TOKEN Mismatch during AXIOS request

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios, request, csrf

Whenever I am requesting my server 2-3 times a second, axios request is going with different X-XSRF-TOKEN header as compare to cookies going with it.

```
let axiosInst = axios.create({
        baseUrl: "MY_BASE_URL_HERE",
        timeout: 20000
      });
function placeRequest() {
  if (data) {
    if (axiosInst) {
      axiosInst
        .post("MY_API_HERE", CryptojsEncrypt(data))
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("success");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log('error');
        });
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

please help me, I just want to send a request with same cookie value and same header everytime,

I tried setting interceptor and transformRequest, so that they can compare header with cookie and if they mismatched request should be aborted at that time, but it didn't worked for me.
I just want my request to be with same header and same value of cookies which are going with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's more than likely because of the parallel nature of these requests.

When you launch a request before the response to the previous one is received, the second request doesn't have access to the new cookie from that first response.

As a result, it will send what the server considers a stale token, but only because your CSRF strategy is wrong (read on).

When you send requests more spaced out, each one has time to come back before the other is launched, meaning they effectively happen sequentially and the token is passed back and forth as the server (incorrectly) expected.

The problem here is actually within your server-side approach to CSRF. You don't need to set & send a new CSRF token in *response* to every XHR/fetch request! Actually, you only need to give a new CSRF when an HTML *page* is being accessed (non-xhr request). Your API endpoints should not even attempt to set a new CSRF. However, they should still require the CSRF set in the user's session from when they got the whole page, in the *request* to the API. But this can stay constant between subsequent XHR/fetch requests unless the user was to hard refresh in their browser.

Setting a new CSRF token on each API request offers no security benefits as well as completely preventing parallel XHR/fetch requests from one user, as you are experiencing.

Hopefully, the server is something you control and not a third party. If it is, then that's where the change needs to happen. We would need more information on its implementation to help.

Comment: I don't have access to server, actually it's a clients project, I can't change anything at backend, can you give any suggestions for the frontend only

Comment: Thats unfortunate. Firstly you should contact them and mention this (as annoying as that is). Unfortunately, the only practical thing you can do on your side is purposefully chain requests such that there is no parallelisation. Though if it's a clients project -- as annoying as it is, you have the ability to influence this, even if you are separate in some way to the back end guys. It's not your problem now, it's theirs! Speaking from experience, you should put your foot down here. If the back end code is accessible I'd be happy to point out the issue.

Comment: Ultimately, preventing parallel requests would be a really bad idea both performance-wise, but also your sanity (increased complexity). It's inherently flakey as well -- if there's a request from a user browser that makes it to the server, but the response does not reach them (very common on poor internet connection), then they are screwed. You should alert the client that you have identified an issue with the backend with confidence and point to this thread if needed. People will also typically respect you for this.

Comment: (and if its more of a case of not wanting to touch the backend due to skills gap, I'm happy to help work through)

Comment: Can't we do something like, we can abort our request if it has a different token than cookies by using interceptors or adapters or transform request, I have tried all with comparing header with present cookie, it always evaluates true stating that cookie and header are same but they are different at the end.